# Swiper slider active class on slides in viewport and current class on one only

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js, swiper.js

I'm trying to set some CSS rules applied to my swiper slides which are currently active and are in the viewport, but the swiper slider only applies `swiper-slide-active` class to one slide not all of the slides in the viewport.
What I want to accomplish is like the slick carousel which for example if you have 3 slides active and in the viewport, they will have `slick-active` class on all of them and `slick-current` class on the current active one.
Is there any way to do so? for some reason, I don't wanna switch to the Slick carousel, I'm looking for a solution for Swiper slider.
By the way, I have set `overflow: visible` to `<div class="swiper-container">`

Here's a snippet:
https://jsfiddle.net/3u05thve/

Comment: please create a working snippet

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3u05thve/

Comment: No way to solve this by swiper API (swiper-slide-active - CSS class name of the currently active slide). Add a screenshot example of the result you want to get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update a swiper to the last version and add this parameter

```
watchSlidesVisibility: true
```

After that, you can control the animation with **swiper-slide-visible** CSS class.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Do slides have to be completely visible in order to get the class "swiper-slide-visible"? The class should only be set if the slide can be fully seen.

Comment: Update: `watchSlidesProgress` and `watchSlidesVisibility` was merged into a single `watchSlidesProgress` in Swiper v7. See [commit](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/commit/33dbf6218ca558fcb14cb68d8dc4ef141be3f7ac).